# How much memory does each types of pointer take , and does it make a difference if they are holding a variables address or not?

Tags: c

When I write this code:

```
int main()
{
    int *b;
    printf("%d", sizeof(b));
}
```

I get `8`, however if I type `*b` instead of just `b` I get `4`:

```
int main()
{
    int *b;
    printf("%d", sizeof(*b));
}
```

The same happens with `void` pointers :

This gives me `8`:

```
int main()
{
    void *b;
    printf("%d", sizeof(b));
}
```

While this gives me `1`:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    void *b;
    printf("%d", sizeof(*b));
}
```

I am just trying to figure out how much memory pointers take depending on their type and if being assigned to hold a variable address makes a difference or not.

Comment: Pointers to different types are *allowed* to have different sizes, but that is extremely unusual nowadays. Anyway, `void*` would be large enough to hold other pointers, so you can check its size. Whether it holds a valid address or not does not affect the size, the bytes are always there. In the tests `*b` is an int, so you get `sizeof(int)` as 4, and not the size of the pointer.

Comment: "figure out how much memory pointers take depending on their type" They take just enough memory to store a pointer on your platform. On some rare platform the size depends on the type. On most common platform it does not. "if being assigned to hold a variable address makes a difference or not" You never assign any value to your pointers, but the size of anything does not depend of which value, if any, is assigned to it.

Answer (score 5):

> How much memory pointers take depending on their type and if being assigned to hold a variable address makes a difference or not.

It makes no difference whether a pointer holds a valid address or not, its size is the same.

The C Standard allows for pointers to different types to have different sizes, with the following constraints:

- A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.
- Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type.
- A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.
- A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

In addition, to allow programs to use pointers to incomplete structure types, all pointers to structure types, complete or incomplete must have the same size.  Similarly, all pointers to union types must have the same size.

Furthermore, the POSIX Standard mandates that all pointers have the same size.

In practice, on architectures with 8-bit addressable bytes, all object pointers have the same size and in most cases, object and function pointers have the same size too.

Yet there are special and historical cases that are still supported by the C Standard:

- systems where function pointers have a different size from data pointers (eg: many compilers for intel 16-bit segmented architectures used to support small, compact, medium, large and even huge memory models, 2 of which having different sizes for object and function pointers).
- systems where 8-bit bytes are not addressable individually, for which `void` and character pointers are larger than other pointer types to store the information to extract single octets from any given word. This was used in some early supercomputers 40 years ago.

Unless you are targeting very exotic architectures, you can reliably assume that all object pointer types have the same size.  Conversely, you should not make assumptions about the sizes of types `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, `unsigned long long` and `size_t` beyond these:

- `sizeof(unsigned short) <= sizeof(unsigned int)`
- `sizeof(unsigned int) <= sizeof(unsigned long)`
- `sizeof(unsigned long) <= sizeof(unsigned long long)`

In particular, `size_t`, the type of `sizeof` expressions, may be:

- the same type as `unsigned int` (32-bit Windows and linux),
- larger than `unsigned int` (64-bit Windows and linux)
- larger than `unsigned long` (64-bit Windows)

The `printf` format for `size_t` values is `%zu`. Here is a modified version of your test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    void *vp;
    int *ip;
    int (*fp)(void);

    printf("sizeof(void *) = %zu\n", sizeof(vp));
    printf("sizeof(int *) = %zu\n", sizeof(ip));
    printf("sizeof(int (*)(void)) = %zu\n", sizeof(fp));
    return 0;
}
```

On legacy systems with C libraries that do not support `%zu`, you can use casts:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    void *vp;
    int *ip;
    int (*fp)(void);

    printf("sizeof(void *) = %u\n", (unsigned)sizeof(vp));
    printf("sizeof(int *) = %u\n", (unsigned)sizeof(ip));
    printf("sizeof(int (*)(void)) = %u\n", (unsigned)sizeof(fp));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil: good point! I had not realised the constraint was slightly less strong than anticipated. Answer amended.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: answer amended.

Answer (score 1):

First notice that `sizeof` return the type `size_t` and printing `size_t` using `%d` is wrong.

The correct way is

```
int *b;
printf("%zu",sizeof(b));
```

When doing `sizeof(b)` you get the size of an **int pointer** (8 in your case) but when you do `sizeof(*b)` you get the **size of the type that b points to**. So that the same as `sizeof(int)` (4 in your case).

This part

```
void *b;
printf("%zu",sizeof(*b));
```

is a bit special. It's like `sizeof(void)` which isn't defined by the standard as it's kind of like "size of nothing". However, some compilers (e.g. some, if not all, gcc versions) still gives the result 1 for `sizeof(void)`. Also notice that `sizeof(void*)` (aka size of void pointer) is legal.

Comment: This part: _It's like sizeof(void) which isn't defined by the standard as it's kind of like "size of nothing"_ is a bit confusing, `void` (nothing) and `void *` (pointer to anything) are not related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/254185

Comment: @DavidRanieri I think he was pointing out that it was semantically meaningless by way of explanation for this OP's observation.  The point is rather laboured however - "undefined behaviour" is perhaps sufficient explanation.